# ASP.NET Core 2.0 request failed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following API controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task Post([FromBody]Statistics value)
        {
            if(_user == null) _user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
            if(_user.Statistics == null) _user.Statistics = new List<Statistics>();
            _user.Statistics.Add(value);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I'm trying to send some data:

```
$("#submit-button-clicked").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api/Statistics ',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    StatX: document.getElementById("input-statisticsX").value,
                    StatY: document.getElementById("input-statisticsY").value,
                    MeasurementDate: document.getElementById("input-datetime").value
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
```

But the request fails (in Visual Studio I get "Failed Requests: 1". I guess routing works as it wouldn't show that request has failed so maybe it's a problem with parsing data?. What could be the problem? (**input-statisticsX** and **input-statisticsY** are just numbers).

*** Statistics class looks like this:

```
 public class Statistics
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public int StatX { get; set; }
        public int StatY { get; set; }
        public DateTime MeasurementDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Use your development console in your browser to see what's happening with the AJAX request. What status code are your receiving? Aside from that, you got some pretty serious problems with your code here. 1) Never directly save anything created from post data (i.e. your param) to the database. Use a view model instead. 2) `UserManager` doesn't bring in related entities, so there's a possibility that `Statistics` might always be `null` here.

Comment: Looks like you have to give an Id property, since it's an `int` and not an `int?` (that is, a nullable int).

Comment: Did you route the controller? You can do it with an attribute in dotnet-core. You should extend your controller from the `Controller` class and decorate it with `[Route("[Controller]")]` `Controller` is a keyword here by the way and you need to name your controller `StatisticsController` for instance

Comment: @Chris Pratt in ajax request I get 404 status code. All values (StatX, StatY, MeasurementDate) looks ok. And thanks for advices

Comment: @Heretic Monkey isn't int = 0 by default? It should be assigned when I put the object into db

Comment: @Yamaç Kurtuluş routing works also without [Route]. Maybe I used a wrong word. It's a part of an API

Comment: Routing can work without attribute thanks to naming convention

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you for clarifying that

Answer (score 1):

As I can see this will be one of the following two things:

1. Either you are not getting StatX, StatY and MeasurementDate values right in your JavaScript code
2. Or you are missing routing attributes for you Post method

I will show you some example code how this can be done, so check out your code to see what is going wrong.

So first I will put some test values in the Post view:

```
<h2>statistics with ajax</h2>
<dl>
    <dt>Stat X</dt>
    <dd id="input-statisticsX">2</dd>
    <dt>Stat Y</dt>
    <dd id="input-statisticsY">3</dd>
    <dt>Measurement Date</dt>
    <dd id="input-datetime">2018-09-06 00:00:00.000</dd>
</dl>
<a id="submit-button">Statistics</a>

@section Scripts {

    <script src="~/js/ajaxTest.js"></script>
}
```

Then in ajaxTest.js file I will check out if we are getting the right values from the view:

```
var value =
    {
        StatX: 0,
        StatY: 0,
        MeasurementDate: ""
    };

value.StatX = document.getElementById("input-statisticsX").innerHTML;
value.StatY = document.getElementById("input-statisticsY").innerHTML;
value.MeasurementDate = document.getElementById("input-datetime").innerHTML;

$("#submit-button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/statistics ',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(value),
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

And finally in the controller I will write Post method like this:

```
[Route("api/statistics")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task Post([FromBody] Statistics value)
{
    var stats = new List<Statistics>();
    stats.Add(value);

    // and some other code ...
    var _user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    // ...
}
```

Done. Check out these three steps in your code and that's all regarding to the parsing problem you might have.
Also not sure what do you want to do with the userManager and user?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution after 2 days. The problem was that I forgot to add repository service in Startup.cs and was looking in wrong place for a solution. API works fine now. Thanks everybody for your time and help.